# Creating a new instance on timer tick performance/GC?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

Currently I have a timer with a tickrate of about 10/s. On every tick it creates a new instance of MyClass.

So basically like

```
var obj = new MyClass(...)
```

and then fetching values from it with

```
lblText.Text = obj.Name();
```

MyClass reads values from memory of other processes and displays them in my form. Why I need to create a new instance everytime on a tick is to update the adresses from my pointers (it's in my `public MyClass()` method).

So my question is:

is it better for performance to create a global instance of MyClass and just make a `Refresh` method I call on every tick? If I understand .NET correctly the GC will at a random(?) interval trigger and collect the unused instances, but until it does its garbage collection will the unused instances just sit there in memory and do nothing? I'm pretty new to programming so I don't really understand what's going on under the hood here.

Comment: You can create *millions* of objects per second.  It just doesn't matter at rates like you use, you'll never notice the difference.  Try it.

Comment: Try and measure yourself. Check out [horses](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) article by Eric Lippert to see how/if you can improve your post.

Comment: The global instance seems the correct way in this case. Like says Hans in the previous comments, you'll never notice the difference from the human perspective, but everytime you create a new instance, you put an overload in the GC, so less instance should be more efficient.

Comment: @KellermanRivero - no, a global instance is more susceptible to errors and might even be less efficient. Short lived memory is very cheap.

Comment: To accomplish performance usually needs an programming carefully. An global instance or an static class, usually needs the use of some type of sync mechanism. Be error prone doesn't means it be less efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it better for performance to create a global instance of MyClass and just make a Refresh method I call on every tick?

It is not possible for anyone here to answer that question with certainty. It is unlikely you would notice a performance difference using a single global instance with refresh versus a brand new object, as 10 objects per second is well under the .NET garbage-collectors theoretical maximum throughput. (One article suggests a realistic throughput of ["tens of millions of small objects per second"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973852.aspx).)

But without actually *testing* the code, it's impossible to know for sure.

> If I understand .NET correctly the GC will at a random(?) interval trigger and collect the unused instances, but until it does its garbage collection will the unused instances just sit there in memory and do nothing?

Yes, the GC periodically cleans up the heap, collecting old, unused objects. Yes, until that happens, you have those unused objects sitting in the heap doing nothing.

Doing nothing, they have no effect on the performance of your program. The definition of "unused" as far as the garbage collector is concerned is "cannot be reached", i.e. there is no connected graph of object references that leads to the object. Since the object cannot be reached, no code can execute any of that object's code.

All the object can do is occupy memory. And that's not generally going to hurt anything.

In general, the rule of thumb for dealing with performance issues is "don't, not yet". That is, your primary focus should be on well-written, correct, understandable code. Once you have done that, then you can look at whether that code performs well enough. Nearly all of the time, it will.

Note that "performs well enough" itself is a loaded phrase. It implies that:

a. you have *measured* your code's performance
b. you have a well-defined performance *goal*, and
c. the measure performance fails to meet the well-defined goal

It is impossible to do any meaningful performance analysis without good measurements and goals.

Only once you've been through all that and have found that rare case where the code doesn't perform well enough, then you can move on to addressing that concern.